# Is there a way in qt interface builder to set the window to appear in the centre of the screen

Tags: qt, qt-creator

When I show my windows they appear off centre. Ive seen examples of fixing this by setting the windows position to the relevant screen co-ordinate. But is there a way of doing this through the the UI Designer.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using

```
    setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);

    setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
```

Please refer this example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-windowflags-example.html